# Selenium popup no source

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, automated-tests, webdriver

I am trying to write a test for selenium to progress an order through a site.  The site is only compatible with IE and it disables the right mouse button.  When I click continue at a certain point, I get a javascript popup window.  On this window I need to select yes, but I am unable to view the source to get the 'id' of the yes button.

Can anyone help me with how I could identify the ids of the buttons or display the source?

Developer tools are not accessible once this window appears.

Comment: When you say 'js-window' you mean new window or something like widget in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a javascript alert then you need to do something like this:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

where driver is the instance of the `WebDriver` you are using.

---- EDIT ----

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
if(js.executeScript("document.readyState")== "complete")
{
  thread.sleep(500);
  driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
}
```

Comment: I get the following  
`org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is active` Could this be an issue with the alert appearing on page load, or before page load?

Comment: @BON sounds like your code is firing before the popup is rendered.  My guess is that the javascript popup fires at document.ready but your selenium fires when the page is loaded so your looking for an alert before the alert script has fired. See my edit for a resolution

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of javascript popups:

1. Alert - it has only "yes" button
2. Confirmation - it has "yes" as well as "no" buttons
3. Prompt - it has input area to write something and "yes" and "no" buttons

You need to make sure which type of popup is shown and act accordingly.